# best practice for bitbucket pipeline deployment in AWS to live server

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I am on a project which is about to release first version. I want to setup bitbucket pipeline when deploying to AWS. When doing so, I am afraid that users on website might be affected while we are deploying. What is the best practice for deploying new feature to the live server without affecting users on the website?

One possible option might be that put maintenance page on the web and deploy new codes when not many users are using the website. is there other way to deploy?

Comment: It depends on your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment it something that depends on underlying tools and technology, but I will focus on your last question.

> One possible option might be that put maintenance page on the web and
>   deploy new codes when not many users are using the website. is there
>   other way to deploy?

First thing, you should not deploy a new feature without proper testing as pipeline must include automating testing, as sometimes such code breaks the complete application.

You should not put application under maintenance during deployment, that is why we have [CI/CD](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/cicd-pipeline) pipeline. You should design your pipeline in the way that you are sure about the lastest code and feature that It should work in production as expected. Many AWS services support blue/green deployment and in the interesting part of blue/green deployment is rollback. You can explore further in the below links.

[AWS_Blue_Green_Deployments](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Blue_Green_Deployments.pdf)

[using-bitbucket-pipeline-for-aws-ecs-deployments](https://medium.com/inspiredbrilliance/using-bitbucket-pipeline-for-aws-ecs-deployments-1a914960f050)

[deploy-to-ec2-with-aws-codedeploy-from-bitbucket-pipelines](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-to-ec2-with-aws-codedeploy-from-bitbucket-pipelines-4f403e96d50c)

[continuous-deployment-pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/continuous-deployment-pipeline/)